# In Excel I want to compare particular cells and take the highest value and place in parent cell when particular cells updates

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Excel screenshot]

1. In the above image, A column is having sum values. I need help me with any formula so that in A13 I need an updated highest value.
2. I am running an automated sequence so first it will update A12 with 90 then 90 should be updated in A13 next again may A9 updates with 101 value so that A9 value should update in A13 so it should lookup in the latest cell and updated the value and should reflects in A13 cell. Help me even if it is macro but also be noticed I am running automated sequences I cannot run the macro manually so I need help with code that runs automatically based on an cell input.

Answer (score 0):

Use the worksheet change event,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub

    Cells(Target.Row, Target.Row) = Target.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much
Can you please brief me exactly what above code DO's is this macro runs automatically or need any manual update where do i have to update the column reference in the code to check the last updated column.